# INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR while accessing paypal REST API

Tags: api, rest, paypal

am getting the below mentioned error, while accessing the paypal rest api:

Array
(
    [name] => INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR
    [message] => An internal service error has occurred
    [information_link] => https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR
    [debug_id] => 9f9e7e8cffced
)

This error is not constant. Can somebody help?

Comment: From the link: `"Resend the request at another time. If this error continues, contact PayPal Merchant Technical Support"`. What did PayPal Merchant Technical Support say when you contacted them?

Comment: Sometimes it happens because of the test credit card number that you used . I will advise you to use credit card numbers other than the one mentioned in PayPal integration guide . like 4446283288203108 , EXPDATE -- 09/2015 , CVV- 012

Answer (score 0):

Is it an internal error on server side, so it is not a problem that you can solve by yourself. The only thing left to do for you is contacting paypal, or wait until they fix the problem, as they are stating in the doc you mentioned:

> Resend the request at another time. If this error continues, contact PayPal Merchant Technical Support.